# Retrieve newest file from memory in android

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I'm running with file deletion problem in android where I want to retrieve last created file and delete it.

Can anyone help with retrieving last created file from android.

Comment: You cannot delete apps private files

Comment: I don't want to delete private file of any app, Just want to delete file that is created in external storage which is doable.

Comment: Which app created that file?

Comment: My application will create that file.

Comment: Then what is the problem exactly?